# Tree viewer gets resized when editor is resized

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

In my Eclipse plugin I have an editor with a tree viewer (specifically saying it is a `FilteredTree`). Initially, the size of the viewer fits in the parent composite.

When I extend some node in the viewer and the amount of children is to high to display all of them in the viewer, the viewer becomes scrollable, and this is OK.

My problem is that when I resize the entire editor part, the viewer gets expanded vertically (horizontally as well, so it is big enough to display all the elements and the scroll bars disappear. How to avoid resizing the viewer?

EDIT:
Some requested details about implementation:
I use `GridLayout` for the viewer itself and also for all the containers above.
The editor is a simple multipage editor. Here is a snippet of the problematic page class implementation:

```java
public class MyPage extends FormPage {  
[...]
  @Override
  protected void createFormContent(IManagedForm managedForm) {
    FormToolkit toolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
    ScrolledForm form = managedForm.getForm();
    Composite body = form.getBody();
    toolkit.decorateFormHeading(form.getForm());
    toolkit.paintBordersFor(body);

    fBlock = new MyMasterDetailsBlock();
    fBlock.createContent(managedForm);
  }
}
```

The `MyMasterDetailsBlock` class inherits from `MasterDetailsBlock`:

```java
public class ModelMasterDetailsBlock extends MasterDetailsBlock{
  [...]
  @Override
  protected void createMasterPart(IManagedForm managedForm, Composite parent) {
    fToolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
    fMasterSection = fToolkit.createSection(parent, ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED|ExpandableComposite.TITLE_BAR);
    fMasterSectionPart = new SectionPart(fMasterSection, fToolkit, 0);
    GridData masterSectionGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true);
    fMasterSection.setLayoutData(masterSectionGridData);
    createTreeEditorBlock();
  }

  private void createTreeEditorBlock() {
    fMainComposite = new Composite(fMasterSection, SWT.FILL);
    fMainComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    fToolkit.adapt(fMainComposite);
    fToolkit.paintBordersFor(fMainComposite);
    fMasterSection.setClient(fMainComposite);
    FilteredTree filteredTree = new FilteredTree(composite, SWT.BORDER, new patternFilter(), true);
    fTreeViewer = filteredTree.getViewer();
    Tree tree = fTreeViewer.getTree();
    tree.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    fToolkit.paintBordersFor(tree);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is depends on the `Layout` you have used. Show us the code you use to create the editor part and the viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the tree you are setting the layout data for the tree to:

```java
tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
```

This is telling the layout that you want the tree to fill all the space. If you want the tree to be a fixed size you need to use something like:

```java
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.TOP, SWT.LEFT, false, false);
data.widthHint = 200;
data.heightHint = 300;
tree.setLayoutData(data);
```

where you choose the width and height hint values.

Comment: Thanks. I just found out this myself examining BuildContentsSection  class of the eclipse plugin development environment. I just came here to answer my own question, but you were faster :-) Thank you again! BTW. it seems OK to set the two last parameters to true. In this case the tree will initially fill all the space, but will not become smaller than the hints.